# Examine data after building Machine Learning model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I built a sentiment analysis model in Arabic; in Python; after building the model, how can I test it with external data and how to build the code for that?

When I fitting the model, I extracted the features via tf-idf, and the problem I faced is dealing with it when I want to test external data after I trained the model on the training and test data.

**summary :
After I trained the model and reached an accuracy of 88%, I want to build a code that tests the model with external data..**

```
# train = 3461 record  
# test = 61 record \
# combi = train + test - to apply tf-idf

train = pd.read_excel('Final_train.xlsx')

test = pd.read_excel('Testing.xlsx' , usecols=['Tweet'])


# merge train & test to apply all function on it 
def combine(tr,te):
   global combi 
   combi = tr.append(te , ignore_index=True)


# this is script to removing all stop words based on NLTK ( Natural Language ToolKit )

def remove_stop(combi1):
    combi1['Tweet'] = combi1['Tweet'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in stop))
    return combi1


#
# this is script to returns Arabic root for the given token Provided by University of Nevada, Las Vegas, USA.

def steeming(combi2):
    st = ISRIStemmer()
    combi2['Tweet'] = combi2['Tweet'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([st.stem(word) for word in x.split()])) 
    return combi2


# This is a List contain many word not Related to our domain we need to remove it from our Dataset
# to make ML Model Work properly & Accurate __ I built it Manually in order to to develop accuracy of model 

def remove_unneded_word(combi3):
    unword =  pd.read_excel('Final_train & MCSA/Un_neededword.xlsx')
    unword = unword.squeeze()
    unword = list(unword)
    combi3['Tweet'] = combi3['Tweet'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x for x in x.split() if x not in unword))
    return combi3

# Calling the Each function Alone 
combine(train,test)
combi = remove_stop(combi)
combi = steeming(combi)
combi = remove_unneded_word(combi)



#                  ______________________________________________
#                 | Term Frequency–Inverse Document Frequency    |
#
#   To Represent Each word as matrix of numbers 

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8,min_df=5, max_features=1600)
# TF-IDF feature matrix
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(combi['Tweet'])




from sklearn import svm #Import scikit-learn  to apply support victor machine Algorithm 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics


train_bow = tfidf[:3641,:]
test_bow = tfidf[3641:,:]

# splitting data into training and validation set
Tr_D_bow, Te_D_bow, Tr_L_bow , Te_L_bow = train_test_split(train_bow, train['Class'], random_state=45, test_size=0.2)
# Create SVM classifer object
SVM = svm.SVC()
# Train SVM Classifer
SVM = SVM.fit(Tr_D_bow,Tr_L_bow)

#Predict the response for test dataset
SVM_pre = SVM.predict(Te_D_bow)



print('The Accuracy of SVMC is -->',metrics.accuracy_score(Te_L_bow, SVM_pre))
```

Comment: Are you asking, how to deploy it? Or how can you make use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test the model (use the model to predict on unseen data), you should use the `.predict` or `.transform` function (with sklearn).

In your code you separated the preprocessing functions and the model training functions which is good. But the fact that you combine the test and the train data is not good. The test data should be your "external data".
Also you tread the TfIdf as a preprocessing step applied to both the test and train data, but the `tfidf_vectorizer.transform` should only be applied to the train data !
If you fit all your data in the TfIdf then you will not know how your model will behave when it haven't seen some words of the input.

With sklearn I usually organize my code as follow:

```py
# Read data
train = pd.read_excel('Final_train.xlsx')

# Split data in test, valid, train
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(
    train, train['Class'], random_state=45, test_size=0.2)

# Define preprocessing functions
def preprocess(data):
    data = remove_stop(data)
    data = stemming(data)
    data = remove_unneeded_word(data)
    return data

# Define sklearn pipeline
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
    max_df=0.8,min_df=5, max_features=1600)
classifier = svm.SVC()

# Train classifier
x_train_preproc = preprocess(train)
x_train_bow = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train_preproc)
classifier.fit(x_train_preproc, y_train)

# Test pipeline
x_valid_preproc = preprocess(valid)
x_valid_bow = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(x_valid_preproc)
pred_valid = classifier.predict(x_valid_bow)
print('The Accuracy of SVMC is -->',
      metrics.accuracy_score(y_valid, pred_valid))

# Save model
# from https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/machine-learning-how-to-save-and-load-scikit-learn-models-d7b99bc32c27
with open('trained_tfidf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(tfidf_vectorizer, f)
with open('trained_classifier.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(classifier, f)

# Load model
with open('trained_tfidf.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    tfidf_vectorizer = pickle.load(f)
with open('trained_classifier.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    classifier = pickle.load(f)

# Predict on unseen data
# Note how the test data have not been loaded until now !
test = pd.read_excel('Testing.xlsx', usecols=['Tweet'])
x_test_preproc = preprocess(test)
x_test_bow = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(x_test_preproc)
pred_test = classifier.predict(x_test_bow)
print(pred_test)
```

The main goal is to be sure to use the test data only when everything has been trained to evaluate the generalization of the model to unseen data.
To make it easier you can combine the TfIdfVectorizer and the SVC into a [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html?highlight=pipeline#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline).
Please note that the code I wrote wasn't tested it is here to show the general steps.